# Wordpress product page automatically changes to 1 product per row

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce website and I have been running into this problem over and over.

I have got product pages with quite a few products on them. Somehow when the page should end (because of the limit of products on a single page i've set). It keeps on going and shows 1 product at a time. I've tried to remove the limit to how many products can be allowed to show on the product page but this does not seem to fix the problem.

I'm not using any code to solve this as of yet. I am not quite sure where to continue to solve this problem. As you can see below the page changes from the normal layout to 1 product per row.

[image: This gif will show what happens.]

Also the page url changes somehow when it shows the new products. For example the url would be:

`example.com/category/`

then:

`example.com/category/page/2/`

Thanks,

Luuc

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code, and details of what you have already tried to work out what is going wrong, so we can see what might be happening and be able to help.

Comment: I've edited the question a little. However I am not using any code to solve this since I don't know what code I should write/use. I'm quite sorry I can't explain the problem any more since I don't know where to begin.